# How to subscribe to particular IMAP folders in Mac Mail

Tags: mail.app, imap

I use Mac Mail to work with an IMAP account. Is it possible to subscribe only to a set of folders, e.g., synchronize only the folder "current" and all its subfolders, but not the folder "archive"? I tried right-click on folder > Account Information > Abonnements/Subscriptions but there no folders are listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> (letter i) in Mail.app, select the account in the popup menu and go to the “Subscription List” tab. From there you should be able to select/deselect shared IMAP mailboxes.

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote in my question, no folders are listed there...

Comment: Is this your own account or a shared IMAP folder from somebody elses account? You can only configure folder subscriptions for shared folders in Mail.app. Your own folders will always be synced.

Comment: Its my own account and no shared folders... so you just gave me the answer that it's not possible ;-)

Comment: strauberry: You correctly interpreted as a no. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems it is still not possible with macOS Sierra mail to unsubscribe from ANY imap folders.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. I am using Mail version 8.2.

I found this to be a fix for me.

When I create a new account in Mac Mail, it shows the account name under "Inbox."

Under that account name are four folders - Sent, Drafts, Junk, and Trash.

You have to click on one folder at a time to highlight it, then in the top menu, select Mailbox > Use This Mailbox As > and select the correct mailbox (Sent, Drafts, Junk, or Trash).

When I did this, my Sent, Trash, Junk, and Draft folders that were under my email account name, moved under the "Main" Sent, Trash, Junk, and Draft sections. It took a second or two for them to sync to the server and not show a warning sign next to the folder name.

Under Mail > Preferences > Accounts > Advanced, I left the IMAP Path Prefix blank. I did change the Port from 143 to 993, checked the Use SSL box, and set the Authentication to Password. I used these settings because they match what my host provider provided me to use for my Incoming Server settings. I'm not sure this mattered or not.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the point.  You can't select a folder to use for those classifications if you can't see it in the first place.